# Linux: access directory with lpr

Tags: linux, lpr

I'm trying to print my text file with 'lpr' in linux Ubuntu

```
import os
import tempfile

s = 'mystring'
f = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
open(f,'w').write(s)

os.system("lpr -P myprinter_name f")
```

but I get this error:

```
lpr: Error - unable to access "f" - No such file or directory
```

How can I create tempfile without getting this error

THANKS!!!

Comment: You need to insert the contents of the variable named `f`, not just put an `f` in your string literal.  Is this python?

Comment: Q: What language?  Note: "f" is a VARIABLE.  You need to pass the VALUE of the variable to the "lpr" command (e.g. "myfile.txt"), not the variable name ("f")...  EXAMPLE: `cmd = "lpr -P myprinter_name " + f`, then `os.system(cmd)`

Comment: Thank you paulsm4 for your help, your code works fine!